# How do I destruct data associated with an object after the object no longer exists?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm creating a class (say, C) that associates data (say, D) with an object (say, O). When O is destructed, O will notify C that it soon will no longer exist :( ... Later, when C feels it is the right time, C will let go of what belonged to O, namely D.

If D can be any type of object, what's the best way for C to be able to execute "delete D;"? And what if D is an array of objects?

My solution is to have D derive from a base class that C has knowledge of. When the time comes, C calls delete on a pointer to the base class.

I've also considered storing void pointers and calling delete, but I found out that's undefined behavior and doesn't call D's destructor. I considered that templates could be a novel solution, but I couldn't work that idea out.

Here's what I have so far for C, minus some details:

```
// This class is C in the above description. There may be many instances of C.
class Context
{
public:
    // D will inherit from this class
    class Data
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Data() {}
    };

    Context();
    ~Context();

    // Associates an owner (O) with its data (D)
    void add(const void* owner, Data* data);

    // O calls this when he knows its the end (O's destructor).
    // All instances of C are now aware that O is gone and its time to get rid
    // of all associated instances of D.
    static void purge (const void* owner);

    // This is called periodically in the application. It checks whether
    // O has called purge, and calls "delete D;"
    void refresh();

    // Side note: sometimes O needs access to D
    Data *get (const void *owner);

private:
    // Used for mapping owners (O) to data (D)
    std::map _data;
};

// Here's an example of O
class Mesh
{
public:
    ~Mesh()
    {
        Context::purge(this);
    }

    void init(Context& c) const
    {
        Data* data = new Data;

        // GL initialization here

        c.add(this, new Data);
    }

    void render(Context& c) const
    {
        Data* data = c.get(this);
    }

private:
    // And here's an example of D
    struct Data : public Context::Data 
    {
        ~Data()
        {
            glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
            glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
        }

        GLint vbo;
        GLint texture;
    };
};
```

P.S. If you're familiar with computer graphics and VR, I'm creating a class that separates an object's per-context data (e.g. OpenGL VBO IDs) from its per-application data (e.g. an array of vertices) and frees the per-context data at the appropriate time (when the matching rendering context is current).

Comment: Thanks all.

In my program there is an update thread and a render thread. The render thread is responsible for rendering twice, once for each eye to create a stereo image. Each 3D object O has eye-specific rendering data D for each context (i.e. for each O there are two copies of D).

The problem: O can be created or destroyed in the update thread, but O's eye-specific rendering data must be destroyed in the render thread, and only when rendering the associated eye.

C needs to know if O is destructed so that in the render thread it will know to destroy both instances of D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is rather vague on the requirements, so it's hard to give a good concrete answer.  I hope the following helps.

If you want the data to disappear immediately when its owner dies, have the owner delete it (and notify C if the C instances need to know).  If you want C to do the deletion at its leisure, your solution looks fine.  Deriving from Data seems to me the right thing to do.  (Of course it is crucial that ~Data() be virtual, as you have done.)

What if D is an array of objects?  There are two interpretations of this question.  If you mean that D is always an array, let it be an array (or vector<>) of pointers to Data.  Then in C::purge() walk the vector and delete the objects.  If you mean that D could be an array of objects but could also be a single object, there are two ways to go.  Either decide that it is always an array (possibly of size 1), or that it is a single object (derived from Data) which can be a class wrapping the array of the actual objects (or pointers to them).  In the latter case, the wrapper class destructor should walk the array and do the deletions.  Note that if you want the array (or vector<>) to contains the actual objects, not pointers to them, (in which case you won't have to walk the array and delete manually) then you'll have the following limitations.  1. All objects in the array will have to be of the same actual type. 2. You will have to declare the array to be of that type.  This will lose you all the benfits of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [Boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), or some similar smart-pointer system.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, "What if D is an array of objects ?", I'd suggest a vector<>, but you'd have to associate it with D:

```
struct D_vector
    :D
{
    vector<whatever> vw;
};
```